# Duplicate string (google_apI_key) in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm having problem almost the same like this one described [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1188) but I don't use Push Plugin. When I try to build Android app with FCM Plugin enabled,
I get this:

```
[string/google_api_key] C:\Projekti\app\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml    
[string/google_api_key] C:\Projekti\app\platforms\android\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error Duplicate resources
1>  :mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

When I remove `<string name="google_api_key">apikey</string>` from *strings.xml* or *values.xml* it simply gets overwritted and build fails.

Does anyone have idea what to do? Cordova and cordova-plugin-fc are at their latest versions. Other plugins are *cordova-plugin-whitelist* and *mx.ferreyra.callnumber*.